# Open file and save it in another function with tkinter

Tags: python, function, file, tkinter

I am working on creating a python Tk program and found that saving files is annoying. I have an open button and a save button. For example I call

```
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='rb',title='Select a file')
```

from this function

```
def open_command(self):
```

In another function

```
def save_file(self):
```

I want to save the file. To save the file under the same name I have to call

```
file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
```

again and this opens another window, then it asks you to name the file, and finaly prompts you if you want to overwrite the file. Is there a way to save the file without any windows? Is it possible in any way to not close the file in one function and then write to the file and save it in another function?

Comment: Do you mean a silent save/overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a silent save/overwrite, so that a user can open a file, modify it, and then hit Save to update the saved file. I would recommend asking for a file *name*, as `askopenfile` asks for the name and then immediately gives you the file object by that name.

```
self.save_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Select a file')
with open(self.save_name, 'rb') as f:
    self.the_data = f.read() # insert processing here
```

If you ask for just the name, you can save that name and then later use it directly in your save function:

```
with open(self.save_name, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(self.the_data) # insert processing here
```

Comment: This helps, but can I only open a file once and then save it after some changes without having to select the file and open another window.(just click 'save' and its done)

Comment: Are you properly saving a reference to the file name you got in `open_command`? The `save_file` function should simply refer to that saved name. It should be able to do so as many times as needed. Is that reference being deleted somewhere?